# Error Can't open data connection in passive mode: connect ETIMEDOUT when upload file at Azure FTP task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-deployment

I got the following error when uploading the release to a ftp server:

> [error]Can't open data connection in passive mode: connect ETIMEDOUT

Here the log:

```
##[section]Starting: FTP Upload: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_AzureTP-ASP.NET Core-CI/drop/ConsoleApp.zip
==============================================================================
Task         : FTP upload
Description  : Upload files using FTP
Version      : 2.157.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload
==============================================================================
connecting to: ****
connected: 220-Microsoft FTP Service
220 ***** FTP
##[warning]Can't open data connection in passive mode: connect ETIMEDOUT *.*.*.*:53909
```

It opens the connection, the log shows 220 state, but then fails.

Comment: Which agent are you using? Hosted agent or private agent?

Comment: Azure pipelines, VS2017-w2016.

Comment: What about using private agent. Host agent is using VM image from Azure DS2_V2. Also, as I know, Azure VM has this limitation which do not support passive mode.

Comment: I changed my path. It is the first docker project in enterprise, so at this time we are still exploring ways to setup the pipeline. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Welcome. If still has such or other similar issue, suggest you raise ticket [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21). In that community, we could involve our product group to work together it by checking some logs from backend.

Comment: I am using FTP Task to deploy code to my home Windows Server 2016 and getting this error - Can't open data connection in passive mode: connect ETIMEDOUT. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Chirag did you find a solution to this? I am in the same shoe as you are right now

Comment: It's working today but i don't recall how i fixed. Maybe the server was filtering the ips.

Comment: I made some changes to my home server, firewall rules and router settings. It’s been long so I will check my settings and get back with the solution